# How to programmatically check if an EC2 instance has finished reboot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I found out that the state of the instance does not change during a reboot. So is there any way to check if the instance has just finished a reboot?

Answer (score 2):

A reboot is an OS level event, so the hypervisor will not be aware of the OS reboot. There is no change during reboot at the API/CLI level that you can detect from command line tools, as you noted.

However, assuming you have ICMP Echo Request enabled in the Inbound Security group, you can use PING to report on the network reach-ability of the instance. This is similar to what the EC2 Status Check does when it reports on instance health.

During a reboot, you will see PING packets dropped momentarily:

```
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=97ms TTL=101
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=80ms TTL=101
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=82ms TTL=101
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=77ms TTL=101
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=106ms TTL=101
```

and then the packet replies return, after the instance has completed it reboot.

I have often used PING in this way to determine when a reboot is complete.  You can do the same programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

[image: instance status]

Using Node SDK, you can use `instanceStatusOk` to check after `rebootInstances`

`instanceStatusOk` > Waits for the instanceStatusOk state by periodically calling the underlying EC2.describeInstanceStatus() operation every 15 seconds (at most 40 times).

Example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#instanceStatusOk-waiter

Comment: After calling Reboot the instance status can be Ok(30 seconds) => Init(3 seconds) => Ok. If this transition happened within 5 seconds then polling every 15 seconds could miss it.